# Ubuntu desktop not showing

Tags: system-installation, tty

When I opened ubuntu for the first time, it installed successfully. But every time I want to boot it. Ubuntu opens a command line instead of the desktop. I searched on the internet for commands but they are not helping.

Does anyone knows what the problem is?

Comment: What version are you using? What happens if you press Ctrl+Alt+F7 all at once?

Comment: If I press ctrl alt f7 I am getting a black screen.... Version is 14.04

Comment: Okay, login to the command prompt (press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to get back to it), or reboot, and then run `sudo lightdm`. It might work (50/50 for me)

Comment: It Didn´t work but kubuntu is installed now and works

Comment: Okay good. Try installing `ubuntu-desktop` if you want unity...